# Regex after text and before the end of the line in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Input:

```
Placed on: Nov 17, 2016 2:27pm
```

Expected result

```
Nov 17, 2016 2:27pm
```

Javascript doesn't support lookbehind and after few hours of looking for solutions - this is what I have currently:

```
[^o][^n]+(?=$)
```

But even though it works here http://regexr.com/3et93 it wouldn't work in javascript... Any other ideas?

PS: First 2 words are always Placed on: (11 characters)...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Could you just use a capture group?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to achieve what you need, and some of them do not even require a regex. Here they are:

- Replace the `Placed on:` with an empty string:

```js
console.log(
  "Placed on: Nov 17, 2016 2:27pm".replace("Placed on: ","")
);
```

- You mention that *First 2 words are always Placed on: (11 characters).*. Use `substr`:

```js
console.log(
 "Placed on: Nov 17, 2016 2:27pm".substr(11)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just capture all characters after `Placed on:` using parenthesis. `match` will give you an array containing captured string.

```js
str = "Placed on: Nov 17, 2016 2:27pm";
result = str.match(/^Placed on:(.*)/);
console.log(result[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
str = "Placed on: Nov 17, 2016 2:27pm";
console.log(str.match(/:\s*(.*)/)[1]);
```

Understand the regex here : https://regex101.com/r/6eLc73/1

Or if we want to use the Placed on text:

try this.

```js
str = "Placed on: Nov 17, 2016 2:27pm";
console.log(str.match(/^Placed\s*on:\s*(.*)/)[1]);
```

Better to use `\s` instead of a hardcoded single spacing.